# gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/user/.gnupg'

Tags: permissions, directory, gpg

System: I am testing [Linux Mint 19 Beta](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3581) based on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes).

I got this warning while installing an unrelated package:

> ```
> gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/vlastimil/.gnupg'
> ```

This is the `ls` output the of the directory itself:

```
$ lld /home/vlastimil/.gnupg

drwx------ 4 vlastimil vlastimil 4,0K Jun 26 11:42 /home/vlastimil/.gnupg
```

That seems to be OK.

This is the `ls` output the contents of the directory:

```
$ ll /home/vlastimil/.gnupg/

total 24K
drwx------ 2 vlastimil vlastimil 4,0K Jun 26 11:36 crls.d
drwx------ 2 vlastimil vlastimil 4,0K Jun 26 05:28 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 6,4K Jun 26 11:42 pubring.kbx
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 3,2K Jun 26 11:37 pubring.kbx~
srwx------ 1 root      root         0 Jun 26 11:38 S.dirmngr
-rw------- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 1,2K Jun 26 11:37 trustdb.gpg
```

I am unsure if I can't just delete the seemingly offending directory named `S.dirmngr`.

I am also unsure if that would solve the issue or create another one.

I just remember that not long ago, I was instructed to install a package named like that, i.e. `dirmngr`, but I can't remember with what software installation it was connected.

**EDIT1:**

As StephenKitt pointed out, I really ran this line, I have found in the history:

```
sudo gpg --recv-keys ...
```

Will this have any consequences?

Comment: I came here looking for the error `unsafe permissions` instead of `ownership`. The solution for that is `find ~/.gnupg -type f -exec chmod 600 {}` and `find ~/.gnupg -type d -exec chmod 700 {}` as can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/oseme-techguy/bae2e309c084d93b75a9b25f49718f85)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is the result of running `gpg` with `sudo`: `gpg` then runs as root, but its home directory is still the user’s. This explains both the warning (`gpg` is running as root but another user owns the configuration directory) and `dirmngr`’s socket’s ownership.

To fix this up, you should stop `dirmngr`:

```
sudo gpgconf --kill dirmngr
```

(`sudo` just this once because `dirmngr` is running as root, as evidenced by its socket), then restore your ownership:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.gnupg
```

Comment: Should I restore the killed process somehow? How do I go about doing that? Also, how do I `sudo gpg` without causing this problem in the first place?

Comment: @leinaD you can’t restore a killed process. To run `gpg` as root without causing this problem, use `sudo -H`: `sudo -H gpg`.

Comment: @StephenKitt After looking at the docs, what i was looking for is `--launch`, I guess, but really I meant to ask if doing something along the lines of `gpgconf --launch dirmngr` was necessary after killing it in the first place.

Comment: @leinaD ah, right, `gpg` should launch `dirmngr` on its own if necessary.

Comment: Alternatively `chown -R $(whoami) ~/.gnupg/` as from [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/oseme-techguy/bae2e309c084d93b75a9b25f49718f85)